# Saving partial postback in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am developing an MVC application and I want to achieve the task of saving comments in a textbox which are checked. The View I will be rendering in the browser for this textbox is a label. I think I will need partial post to achieve this and I don't know how to achieve this. Any suggestions are welcome and any links will help.

CheckBox   >>  Textbox
The checkbox the user checks will be a partial post, I don't want a complete postback, so I am using MVC to achieve this.

And in the returned partial view I should be getting:
Label  >> in the form of stack.

Comment: you can make an ajax call on checkbox check change event using jquery

Comment: so you want to tell me that we cant make ajax calls in mvc

Comment: i dont know using ajax with MVC. please provide some example or link and also with javascript if possible. - @Rex

Comment: You could use google, for more simplicity, search "ajax call with aspnet mvc" :)